# makefile, rule for multiple inputs

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

have one time consuming step that flattens a bunch of files.

basically i'd like this to be valid syntax

```
%.out: %.input1 %.input2
    merge $<1 $<2 $@

doit: project.out
    # project.out merged
```

i'm far from a makefile expert, but i like to use .SULFFIXS to do that when only have two files, would be great to adapt that to two inputs, or two outputs for future use...

```
.SULFFIX: .in.out
.in.out:
    dosomething $< $@
doit: project.out
```

GNU Make 3.81

I've found several discussions on how to have a rule with several outputs, but none with several inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%.out: %.input1 %.input2
    merge $<1 $<2 $@
```

There are no `$1` and `$2` automatic variables in makefile rules, however, there is [`$^`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_0024_005e-948) which is the list of all prerequisites. As the rule only has two prerequisites it expands to `%.input1 %.input2`, or, more precisely, to `$*.input1 $*.input2`. Hence:

```
%.out: %.input1 %.input2
    merge $^ $@
```

Should suffice.

`.SULFFIXES`, IMO, is not very useful, since it uses implicit rule definitions which one can't see and change.

**[update]**

With regards to `doit` target, to prevent it from executing every time you might like to change the rule commands to:

```
doit: project.out
    # project.out merged
    touch $@
```

Comment: good point, forgot about $^... and what if all i need for the command is the first one? am i out of luck?

Comment: ok, just tested, with your example $< is the first file. everything went better than expected. thanks

Comment: hum, but with that pattern, everytime i run the doit rule it's executed.

Comment: `doit` rule doesn't produce the file it promises to produce, hence it is always executed to produce `doit` file. It's similar to a `.PHONY` target, with the exception that if `doit` file exists it won't be executed, unless it's older than its prerequisites (`project.out`).